# How to get data from database table in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to get the data that has been stored in my database to print in my website.I want to input the user entered word and then store it in a table after that i want it to show on a page.I have already saved created a form that takes the user entered data and stores it in a table but have not been able to display the data.I want the data entered by the user be available in any file

**Here is my View**

```
     <form class="form-horizontal"
action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/submit/new_form_submit" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Title">Title</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="Title" name="Title" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Price">Price</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="Price" name="Price" type="number" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">

    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Textarea -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textarea">Describe your product</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" name="textarea"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Link">Link to Live preview</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="Link" name="Link" type="url" placeholder="e.g  http://www.example.com" class="form-control input-md" required="">

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- File Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="filebutton">Screenshot of your theme</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="file-input">
                <!--  <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="<?/*= base_url() */?>Images/placeholder.jpg"/>
                    </div>-->
            </label>
            <input id="file-input" type="file"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <!-- Button (Double) -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="button1id"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            <a id="cancel" name="cancel" class="btn btn-danger" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home">
                Cancel</a>
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

**Here is my Controller**

```
    <?php

session_start();

class Submit extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->helper('security');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('Submit_Database');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}



public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('submitf/submit');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function new_form_submit()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Title', 'Title', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/home');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    } else {

        $data = array(
            'Title' => $this->input->post('Title'),
            'Price' => $this->input->post('Price'),
            'textarea' => $this->input->post('textarea'),
            'Link' => $this->input->post('Link')
        );

        $result = $this->Submit_Database->submit_insert($data);
        if ($result == TRUE) {
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/about');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('submitf/submit');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }




    }
    redirect('');
}

}
```

**Here is my model**

```
   <?php

Class Submit_Database extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(); // construct the Model class
        $this->load->database();
    }

// Insert registration data in database
    public function submit_insert($data)
    {


// Query to insert data in database
        $this->db->insert('submit', $data);

    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: First thing I would like to know, where you need to display data?

Comment: Here's an idea:  [follow the tutorial in the documentation where they show you exactly how it's done](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: I want to display it in a page called productview

Answer (score -1):

The logic is this:
You need a function in model to select from the database.
A function in controller to call the model function and load the view with the data. 
And a view file to actually display the data.
You can use sessions in order to store the data in a session variable and access it in any file. You have to load the session library.